# jqgrid custom unformat not called when getrowdata()

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, formatter

I used custom formatter and unformat for the column in jqGrid:

```
{name: 'STATUS', index: 'STATUS',width:145,align:'center',fixed:true, formatter:statusFormatter, unformat:statusUnFormatter}
```

Formatter:

```
function statusFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    var icon = '';
    var label = '<span class="label status-label">';
    switch (cellvalue){
        case 'Rejected': {
            icon = '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>'; 
            label = '<span class="label label-primary status-label">';break;}
        case 'Approved': {
            icon = '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>'; 
            label = '<span class="label label-primary status-label">';break;}   
        default: break;
    }
    return label + icon+"&nbsp" +cellvalue + '</span>';
}
```

Unformat:

```
function statusUnFormatter(cellvalue, options, cell){
    var html = '<div>' + cellvalue + '</div>';
    html.find('i').removeClass();
    html.find('span').removeClass();
    return html.text();
}
```

Table looks like this:
[Column after formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7byCv.png)

Problem happens when I use getrowdata(), it returns the content instead of the original value of the cell. [Result of alert()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DuZp.png)

```
onCellSelect: function(id, icol, cellcontent, e){
    var status = $(this).getRowData(id).STATUS;
    alert(status);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in my unformat function. 
I did not wrap the string in a jQuery object, so the text() method doesnt work.

This code works:

```
function statusUnFormatter(cellvalue, options, cell){
    var text = $('<div>' + cellvalue + '</div>').text();
    return text.trim();
}
```